# Truncated answer

Tags: bug, specific-answer, truncation, old-posts

Why is this answer truncated: [Why are many of the banking sites implemented in Java rather than .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427675/5542)?

[image: Truncated]

While long, it should not exceed the maximum length and the source contains the full text:

[image: Source]

Comment: This question is horribly nonconstructive and will hopefully be closed post-haste now that you have bumped it into the collective attention span.

Comment: @Rosinante - It is now closed and on its way to deletion...

Comment: Subject **and** argumentative to the nth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was rather old and this is probably a result of a bug in the markdown parser at the time - the generated HTML was never updated (until now with my edit adding a space).

It is now perfectly fine.

Comment: I would have +1'ed this answer if you had ended with *"It is now perfectly"*